# How to add pagination in react native from api

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my API and I want to call this API in my react native code and this should be in pagination

```
"Pagination": {
    "showing": "Showing 1-10 of 61  results",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "PREV",
            "onclick": 1,
            "value": 0,
            "disabled": " disabled ",
            "active": " "
        },
        {
            "name": "1",
            "onclick": 0,
            "value": "1",
            "disabled": " disabled ",
            "active": " active "
        },
        {
            "name": 2,
            "onclick": 1,
            "value": 2,
            "disabled": " ",
            "active": " "
        },
        {
            "name": 3,
            "onclick": 1,
            "value": 3,
            "disabled": " ",
            "active": " "
        },
        {
            "name": "NEXT",
            "onclick": 1,
            "value": 2,
            "disabled": " ",
            "active": " "
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use FlatList and passing a callback method to onEndReached you can fetch paginated data. Ref. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold

ex: https://snack.expo.dev/@mkpeak/react-native-flatlist-pagination-to-load-more-data-dynamically---infinite-list